# Adding Magi-Tech to 5E

Tags: dnd-5e, campaign-development, world-building

I am going to be running a 5th Edition campaign set in a future of a previous campaign. I want to add "magi-tech", but very sparingly.

My question is: Are there any official sources for this type of thing? Rules or anything? I know 5E is new so it might not, but I thought I'd ask.

I've heard that Eberron has some magi-tech things (I've never played it). Would the campaign guide for 4E be good to pull ideas from or would it not make sense rules-wise?

Comment: Regarding your final paragraph: [Editions of D&D are not cross-compatible](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49033/is-4th-edition-dd-compatible-with-5th-edition). So you can pull *ideas* from Eberron, but the rules won't make the transition. That said, 3rd Edition Eberron is probably marginally closer mechanically than 4E Eberron (though still not really compatible).

Comment: For some reason, I thought I remembered reading that 5e is made to be able to be somewhat compatible with all editions with minimal changes.

Comment: That is not correct. 5e draws inspiration from a number of editions (particularly the earlier ones) but is ultimately its own system.

Comment: Can you explain or give an example of what you mean by "magi-tech"?

Comment: Well I mean using magic as a form of science. Kind of like steampunk but with magic as a form of power instead of steam. Like in Eberron there is a lightning rail powered by magic.

Answer (score 8):

In the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (pp. 267-268), there are rules for firearms, including future items (e.g., laser pistol, antimatter rifle and a laser rifle, along with modern weapons). Also explosives, including grenades. There are also rules on 'alien technology' in the DMG  (pg 268) which is rules for a character figuring out how to use technology works.

For most technology (magi-tech or otherwise), I would use these rules and simply treat it as a magic item with similar properties. Jet pack is a broom of flying, a computer is a scroll of some divination spell (with recharging charges) and a hovercraft is an airship or flying carpet, etc., perhaps with limited charges.

Since the DMG also features guidelines on making spells, you can make up an ability with those guidelines and treat items as either scrolls or wands to simulate technology.

Answer (score 2):

I made gnometech and try to keep it simple.

I take a magic item and make it look like a steampunk creation.  Examples are
 *boots of jumping and springing* that have small rockets on the side of the bronze/brass boots with a gooey (super rubber) sole.
I sometimes up the rarity and combine two items together, or give it some aspects of another item.
Example: the above rocket boots also allowing a swimming speed.

Gnometech can also be, more generically, magitech.  I have Kobolds, Goblins and Dwarves with their own variations.  It's a way to reskin an item to fit your campaign style better.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Please take the [tour] for an intro to how we do things around here.  The core of this answer (refluff existing magic items into magitech versions that work similarly) is workable advice, but this answer would be improved by providing more details to [back it up](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/what-kind-of-answering-guidelines-should-we-have/627#627), especially info about how this worked out in the game(s) where you tried it.

Comment: Forgotten Realms and Krynn had some gnomish tech back in 1E & 2E that certainly verged on magitech. Usually gnomish tech came up in books and games when a non-magical item was needed that was too advanced for the medieval/renaissance era.